# How to implement AddAdiditions in React Sematic UI using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui

I want to have a drop down in my application which allows the user to add an item to the dropdown. I am using React Sematic UI.
[Sematic UI Dropdown ALlowAdditions](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-allow-additions)

I am new to react hooks and I want to know how I can implement the onChange and onAddition function using hooks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 'English', text: 'English', value: 'English' },
  { key: 'French', text: 'French', value: 'French' },
  { key: 'Spanish', text: 'Spanish', value: 'Spanish' },
  { key: 'German', text: 'German', value: 'German' },
  { key: 'Chinese', text: 'Chinese', value: 'Chinese' },
]

class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends Component {
  state = { options }

  handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      options: [{ text: value, value }, ...prevState.options],
    }))
  }

  handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ currentValue: value })

  render() {
    const { currentValue } = this.state

    return (
      <Dropdown
        options={this.state.options}
        placeholder='Choose Language'
        search
        selection
        fluid
        allowAdditions
        value={currentValue}
        onAddItem={this.handleAddition}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default DropdownExampleAllowAdditions
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const options = [
  { key: "English", text: "English", value: "English" },
  { key: "French", text: "French", value: "French" },
  { key: "Spanish", text: "Spanish", value: "Spanish" },
  { key: "German", text: "German", value: "German" },
  { key: "Chinese", text: "Chinese", value: "Chinese" }
];

const DropDownWithHooks = () => {

  const [dropDownOptions, setDropDownOptions] = useState(options);
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState("");

  const handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    setDropDownOptions((prevOptions) => [
      { text: value, value },
      ...prevOptions
    ]);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, { value }) => setCurrentValue(value);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      options={dropDownOptions}
      placeholder="Choose Language"
      search
      selection
      fluid
      allowAdditions
      value={currentValue}
      onAddItem={handleAddition}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};


export default DropDownWithHooks;
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-35yc3?file=/example.js:0-1061)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I see its giving an error when we try to add an item. Checked in sandbox @Shyam

Comment: I'm getting this error at onChange and onAddItem in return statement. 

Type '(e: any, { value }: { value: any; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>, data: DropdownProps) => void'.
  Types of parameters '__1' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'DropdownProps' is not assignable to type '{ value: any; }'.
      Property 'value' is optional in type 'DropdownProps' but required in type '{ value: any; }'.ts(2322)

In the sandbox also, when we try to add item, its giving error

Comment: I am not getting any errors from the sandbox which i have added in my answer . Are you using something different ? If yes can you send the sandbox link which is giving you errors ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-35yc3?file=/example.js

Comment: That's strange i am not seeing any errors . Can you tell me the steps to reproduce the error ?

Comment: Just opened the sandbox link and tried to add an item in the dropdown.
Anyways, in the line { text: value, value } , is it not necessary to give key as well ?

Comment: There was a small change I had to do, 
{ key:value, text: value, value }
Thanks a ton for the help. Mad e my day.